# Screen not turning on with wake lock in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, wakelock

I have a foreground service that is waiting for a shake. When it receives that motion, it sends out a broadcast with:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.company.app.shakeDetectedMessage");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

My main activity receives this with a broadcast receiver which implements the method:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MainActivity.this.turnOnScreen();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And my turn on screen method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I have a partial wake lock with

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SensorRead");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

declared in the service

Yet, when I turn my screen off and shake, the screen doesn't turn on! I verified that every method is working with logs. The onReceive is working even when the screen is off. The broadcast is working. Just the screen won't turn on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

call the acquire method of WakeLocker class

**Class :**

```
public abstract class WakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

**Permission Required**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
    PowerManager powerManager = getService(this, POWER_SERVICE);
    mScreenLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "Lock");
    mScreenLock.acquire();
```